# Which is the best Analytics and error logging tool in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, analytics

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 app. But when I tried implementing Analytics tools and error logging tool I found very few of them. They are Crittercism, localytics, Google Analytics, Flurry. But none provided complete functionality like in Android or ios.

Which Analytic tool for Windows Phone 8 App can provide following feature?

- Log Events with multiple Data to slice and data into meaningful information.
- Log request and response time for web service call Log
- Battery usage
- Log memory usage
- Send Push notification
- Log Errors and Crashes Application
- Response time
- Performance Analyzer